# Convert Excel (.xml) file with Aspose.Pdf file PDF

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, aspose

I'm using the CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter API and the Aspose.Pdf API. As I'm using the .xml file that CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter API created and using it to creat a .pdf file with the Aspose.Pdf API I'm getting a blank .pdf file with no data in it except the Aspose watermark..

It's seems that Aspose PDF is not recognizing the tags in CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.xml so when using Aspose.Pdf the .pdf file is not populated with any data.

I've checked the Aspose.Pdf API documents and forum but I didn't see anything that they mentioned about Aspose .Pdf API is able to convert any .xml file to PDF..

Comment: Did you get any error? Did you try Aspose.Cells to read the XML? The `Workbook` class can save PDF, too.

Comment: No I didn't get any error or used the Aspose.Cells should I?
The problem is that I need to use the already Workbook obj that CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter created as I need to not touch the already created Workbook but yet to creat a .pdf file from it..

Comment: Also is the Aspose.Cell can recognize the foreign tags so it can create a dynamic .pdf file?

Comment: You can always give their Aspose.Cells trial a try for free and test if it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

My name is Nayyer and I am Support Developer / Technical Evangelist at Aspose.

Aspose.Pdf for .NET is supports the feature to convert XML files into PDF format but the  source XML file must be according to [Document Object Model](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Aspose.Pdf+for+.NET+Document+Object+Model+%28DOM%29) of Aspose.Pdf for .NET. The reason you are not seeing anything in resultant PDF, is because the XML schema is not compliance to Aspose.Pdf DOM. If you prefer to use the XML generated with CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter API, you may try using XSLT to make the source XML file compatible with Aspose.Pdf.Generator DOM.

You may check the following links for further details on [Introduction to XML Technologies](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Introduction+to+XML+Technologies+%28Generator%29).

*PS, If the XML file is compliant with Open Office XML format, then you can simply use Aspose.Cells for .NET instead of Aspose.Pdf for .NET to render this file into PDF format. You may check the following link for more information on [File Formats supported by Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/SpreadsheetML+%28XLSX,+XML%29).*

Comment: Thanks, but for now i'm using other approch for converting an XML to PDF.

Comment: Do you still face any issue while using XML to PDF conversion or the problems are resolved ?

Comment: The truth is that I didn't try to mess with Aspose.Pdf for .NET again in a while, but Is there any way to pass to an instance of Aspose.Pdf for .NET (or other Aspose API) an object of the the above issue and then to get a PDF?